# Android accelerometer usage

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am new to android and trying to make an application that can detect vehicle speed acceleration and deceleration using android accelerometer.

Can anyone suggest good tutorials on accelerometer that can help me with this.

Also I wanted to know in order to display the details captured by accelerometer do we have to maintain a database?

Comment: this is a good tutorial for android accelerometer http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports several sensors via the SensorManager. For example the accelerometer, Proximity etc.

Read from here.

[Link1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html)

[Link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

[Link3](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)

To display the values you can use and its displayt the values in logcat.

```
Log.v("Appname",values[0]);
```